# TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Subscribers

Tags: django, django-models, typeerror

```
class Subscribers(User):
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Tour(models.Model):
    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(Subscribers, related_name="sub")
```

I am trying to do this in another file:

```
user1 = User.objects.create_user('John','j@j.com','j1')
user2= User.objects.create_user('Mike','m@m.com','m1')
user3= User.objects.create_user('kokoko','m@m.com','m1')
user4= User.objects.create_user('lalal','m@m.com','m1')
sub = Subscribers()
tour = Tour()
tour.id = "1"
tour.name = "hello"
tour.owner_id = user1
tour.subscribers = sub
```

but I have this error:
TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Subscribers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ManyToMany manager assumes that when you do

```
tour.subscribers = sub
```

`sub` is a sequence (tuple, list, queryset) of `Subscribers`, not a single object. Then doing so is the exact same as doing:

```
tour.subscribers.add(*sub)
```

And since sub is not a sequence, it throws such error. I would recommend saving first and adding later. I think it's also more readable, but it may be just my opinion:

```
sub = Subscribers()
tour = Tour()
tour.id = "1"
tour.name = "hello"
tour.owner_id = user1
tour.save()
tour.subscribers.add(sub)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have tried that but I get ValueError: Cannot add "<Subscribers: >": instance is on database "default", value is on database "None"

Comment: It's because you are trying to add subscribers to a tour before saving the tour, I've had such problem before :)

Comment: Thank you I agree that it looks better and solves the problem of the sequence!!But saving first does not solve the general problem!